# Config File Loads Twice

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter. Suddenly, for some reason, my application/config/config.php started loading twice.

I have the following code at the top of config file, starts from line 5 to line 12:

```
function __autoload ($class) {
    $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT;
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once (APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT);
        }
    } 
}
```

When i test a page, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php:5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 12
```

If i wrap the autoload with `if(!function_exists('__autoload')) { ... }`, i get the following output:

```
    Notice: Constant FRONTEND_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 390

    Notice: Constant FRONTEND_WEBPARTS_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 391

    Notice: Constant FRONTEND_MAINPAGES_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 392

    Notice: Constant BACKEND_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 393

    Notice: Constant BACKEND_WEBPARTS_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 394

    Notice: Constant BACKEND_MAINPAGES_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 395

   Notice: Constant BACKEND_MAINPAGES_PATH already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_centric\application\config\config.php on line 396
    .
    .
    .
```

Everything used to work fine for days; i played little bit with $this->session->flashdata('...'); then i got the config double loading problem.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: To load my custom controller frontend_controller and backend_controller that reside in Libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know what kind of hacks do you use, and WHY do you do such things in a `configuration` file, where only variables should be declared. You should remove that code or better even start from a fresh copy of CodeIgniter. You don't know where and for what purpose CodeIgniter wants to load this file twice. Anyway, you should not do such things by any means. If it's really necessary for some awkward reason, you can try moving this to `MY_core.php` or even `index.php` file, it's still will be totally wrong, but much better than what you have right now.

Comment: Nice, well, that guy surely just couldn't find a better way to store a function, than in a file which name AND folder says it's NOT for functions or anything else. This is wrong. The whole controller stuff might be useful, but guys developing CodeIgniter provided you with basically lots of ways how to override standard functionality and this one is definitely not one of them.

Comment: Solved!

I defined BACKEND_MAINPAGES_PATH twice ... What a silly error ... For me, its a good temporary solution anyway ...

Comment: This method is called 'Native Auto-load' and was introduced by Phil Sturgeon to extend CodeIgniter's base controllers: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY. I've faced the same problem like @user311509 so I've moved the autoload function to index.php. It seems to work fine now but I'm still wondering, why my config file is loaded twice.

Comment: @PhilippMikael I think it may happen as CodeIgniter loads the config file once in the beginning and once again when it loads all user config files, but it's just a guess, some code inspection is required to say for sure